# What is the difference between directive function and informational function of a language?

Tags: semantics, meaning

In Geoffery Leech, Chapter 4, Semantics The Study of Meaning, It is written that

> "The third function of language is the directive function whereby we aim to influence the behaviour and attitudes of others. The most straightforward instances of the directive function are commands and requests. The function of social control places emphasis on the receiver's end, rather than the originator's end of the message; but it resembles the expressive function in giving less importance on the whole to conceptual meaning than to other types of meaning, particularly affective and connotative meaning."

How does the directive function give less importance to conceptual meaning? When we give an instruction aren't we passing on information that is supposed to be executed in its literal sense? What is the difference between directive function and informational function?

Comment: Sounds like Aristotle's distinction between the intellect and the will re-enacted. Also the distinction between semantics and pragmatics. As for information, consider how much more likely people might be to do something that we want if we lie to them about the reasons we want it.

Comment: @jlawlerSo, are you saying that directive function is more "direct" in its approach of getting someone to do something, whereas the informational function is a more persuasive/manipulative way of getting someone to do something?

Comment: That depends on what Leech would include in his category. He says orders and requests are "the most straightforward" kinds, but dropping a hint and raising an intonation, or an eyebrow, are much less straightforward and shade off into many other social dimensions.